# PalindromeChecker comparTo

Tags: java

I am trying to make a Palindrome (the inverse of word is the word self e.g. tacocat) checker in java.
I use this code:

```
private static void PalindroomChecker(String sWord){
    char[] arrcWord=sWord.toCharArray();
    char[] arrcDrow=new char[arrcWord.length];
    for(int i=0;i<arrcWord.length;i++)
        for(int j=arrcDrow.length-1;j>=0;j--)
            arrcDrow[j]=arrcWord[i];
    String sDrow=new String(arrcDrow);
    if(sWord.compareTo(sDrow)==0)
        System.out.println(sWord);
    else
        System.out.println("false");
}
```

for some reason I keep printing false. So for some reason there are no palindrome's not even tacocat.

Comment: why do you need two loops?

Comment: so i can reverse the first array in the second

Answer (score 0):

you only need the index. This should work.

```
    private static void PalindroomChecker(String sWord) {
    char[] arrcWord = sWord.toCharArray();
    char[] arrcDrow = new char[arrcWord.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = arrcDrow.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        arrcDrow[j] = arrcWord[i++];
    String sDrow = new String(arrcDrow);
    if (sWord.compareTo(sDrow) == 0)
        System.out.println(sWord);
    else
        System.out.println("false");
}
```

Comment: indeed it did. I completly understand your code but I don't get why my way doesn't work. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: your code doesn't work because you have got the wrong logic. you are setting the value of i-th index at this line `arrcDrow[j]=arrcWord[i];`. so when i is 0 it will the set the 0-th index value at all the place in `arrcDrow` and when i reaches at the last index, you will have `arrcDrow` filled with the same value. 

Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Oh My God indeed. Now I get it. I am very sorry for being this stupid. God dammit why didn't I see this myself. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

you might have got why your code doesn't work from other answers... here is a no loop approach it's much simpler::

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String yourString = "tacocat";
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder(yourString);
    System.out.println(a.reverse().toString().equals(yourString) ? true : false);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could remove spaces and compare with equalsIgnoreCase()